# Material-UI ThemeProvider not passing theme to components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've created a theme in my App.js which overrides the Primary and Secondary color. I have ThemeProvider wrapping a Home component. The overridden values are not showing up in the Home component. What am I doing wrong?

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple'
import green from '@material-ui/core/colors/green'

import Home from './components/Home'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    pallete: {
      primary: {
        main: purple[500]
      },
      secondary: {
        main: green[500]
      }
    }
  }
})


const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Home />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
export default App
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Container, Grid, AppBar, Toolbar, CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core'

const Home = () => {
    const theme = useTheme()

    return (
        <Container max="lg">
            <CssBaseline />
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <AppBar color="primary">
                        <Toolbar>
                            Hello World
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                </Grid>
            </Grid >
        </Container >
    )
}
export default Home

I would think that in my AppBar the color="primary" should show up with the overridden primary color. But it's not happening.
```

Comment: I guess you need to override the Appbar props in your muitheme. See this link - https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css

Also in case you need to override it at component level then you need to override it by using makeStyles and adding the speicified CSS property for that rule.

Comment: @Mohit i suppose, he on a right way. If he wants to override whole `palette` in app he needs to use `ThemeProvider` as he tried. More specific overrides needs to override more specific things. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got some typo (like `pallete` instead of `palette`, redundant `overrides` prop etc).

Here a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-snow-z1vnp?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. (Sorry bout the typos, eesh). You used MuiThemeProvider instead of ThemeProvider, can you explain? I've read the difference but don't quite understand yet.

Comment: @user3831527, right now it's synonym, but it will be removed in MUI V5. I'm sorry, I just used it on a habit. Use `ThemeProvider` instead.